# Flexbox: Flex-Item Aside

Tags: css, flexbox

[image]

Hello, I've tried to achieve this design to no avail. Regarding the 2nd item: `align-self: stretch` doesn't work, and `flex-basis` only applies to the main axis. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't move the 3rd item up into the first item's row using flexbox. If box 1 and 3 are the same height, you could potentially use `transform: translateY(-100%)` to move it back up, but that's a hack. You  might want to look at using css columns http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/ or a plugin like http://masonry.desandro.com

Answer (score 5):

Here it's imo you can do. but with your code it should be better to help you

```css
.container{
  width : 100vw;
  height : 100vh;
  display:flex;
}
.sub-container1{
  flex : 1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  background-color : #245878;
}
.item1{
  flex:1;
  background-color : #214585;
  margin : 5%;
  
}
.item2{
  flex:1;
  background-color : #548789;
  margin : 5%;
}
.sub-container2{
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  background-color : #451589;
}
.item3{
  flex:1;
  background-color : #236589;
  margin : 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class="sub-container1">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <div class="item2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container2">
    <div class="item3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```